# Using CCLabelBMFont gives error TextureCache: fileimage MUST not be nil

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have created MyFont.fnt file and MyFont.png file. Ang have written the following code

```
CCLabelBMFont *replyText = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"MyText" fntFile:@"MyFont.fnt"];
replyText.position = ccp(winSize.width/2 + 20, winSize.height-200);
[self addChild:replyText z:index++];
```

But it's giving and error and i have no idea why. I have done clean and build again process also deleted files but had no luck. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after hours of looking into this silly issue found the problem. my .fnt file had xml tags i exported it as text and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside `MyFont.fnt` and see what .png file it refers to. Then check if this .png file is all right. Since you have this error that file is definitely not all right. It is either missing in the project or have different name. For example in the .fnt file you refer to it as `MyFont.png` but it is actually called `MFont.png`.

Inside the .fnt file search for the line `file="filename.png"`